# SMB mount - no write access by terminal but by gui

Tags: bash, mount, smb

I want to mount a SMB share by the following command of a bash script, which works perfectly:

```
    read -p "username : " user_var
    read -sp "password : " pass_var
    echo
    sudo mount -t cifs -w -o  domain=Geo,username="$user_var",password="$pass_var",iocharset=utf8,vers=3.0 //smb.share.de/geo  /media/Geo 
ret=$?
        unset user_var
        unset pass_var
```

But I've got no write access there as user.
Besides when I mount it manually by the GUI I can also write there and it's also mounted differently:

[image]

By gui it's mounted as network device but by terminal just a device. I'm not the host of the share.

How can I gain write access with my terminal mount command?

Comment: Can you write into ```/media/Geo``` when you try as root ? Mount it first via the terminal not GUI.

Comment: As root I can write there.

Comment: So you have to make your user the owner of the mount point . Do it via adding the option ```uid=$(id -u) to the list of mount options(i.e starts with `-o` and before the filesystem address).

Comment: Thanks for the clue, it works with 'uid=$(id -u)' as well as 'uid=$USER'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make your user the owner of the mount point.Do this by adding the `uid=$(id -u)` option to the **mount** command :

```
sudo mount -t cifs -w -o   uid=$(id -u),domain=Geo,username="$user_var",password="$pass_var",iocharset=utf8,vers=3.0 //smb.share.de/geo  /media/Geo
```